# adding methods from class A to a delegate of class B and calling that delegate from class A in C#

Tags: c#, methods, delegates

How can I add a method from class A to a delegate of class B without knowing in advance which method I will be adding and what class A is? And then call that delegate from class A?

```
class Class {
    public string someProperty;

    public delegate void myDelegate(Class obj);

    myDelegate handler = new myDelegate(mainClassMethod); //here is the problem..

    public void someMethod() {
        handler();
    }
}

class MainClass {
    public static void Main() {
        Class classObj = new Class();

        classObj.someProperty = "hello";

        public void mainClassMethod(Class obj) {
            System.Console.WriteLine(obj.someProperty);
        }

        classObj.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Should I use something other than delegates for this? By the way I am doing this in C#!

Comment: it would help if you use the same names in example as in text, and what's the problem exactly? compiler error?

Comment: not really, the problem is that I want to call, in MainClass, a method from Class that calls a method from MainClass. Except that I want to specify which method from MainClass that method from Class is gonna call from the MainClass. So it's kind of like this: a method from Class is called every time I press a button, and I want that method (the one that is called every time I press a button) to call a method from MainClass. But I want to specify which method from MainClass is gonna be called (by the method that is called in Class every time I press a button) inside MainClass. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

make `mainClassMethod` static and access it via class name `MainClass`. Also you cant declare nested functions as class members, you need to declare `mainClassMethod` separately.

```
class MainClass {
    public static void Main()
    {
        Class classObj = new Class();

        classObj.someProperty = "hello";

        classObj.someMethod();
    }

    public static void mainClassMethod(Class obj) 
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(obj.someProperty);
    }
```

}

Also you declared delegate `void myDelegate(Class obj);` so you need to pass instance of a `Class` as a parameter. In my example I pass object found by `this` reference, which is an object that you call `someMethod` at.

Now you can write:

```
class Class {

    public string someProperty;

    public delegate void myDelegate(Class obj);

    myDelegate handler = new myDelegate(MainClass.mainClassMethod); //no error

    public void someMethod() 
    {
        handler(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay but I would like mainClassMethod to access private variables though. And also I don't know what class A is in advance. Can I instantiate an object from an unknown class?